# How to get python notebook path from Azure databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I want to get exact python/scala file path which are created at workspace or user level.

In Azure Datafactory Python activity, I want to execute the python notebook which is part of my workspace.

If I upload the .py file in dbfs, ADF pipeline gets executed.

But I don't want to upload file in dbfs.

How to call python files in Python activity of Azure data factory?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  [Azure Databricks Notebook Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook) in a Data Factory pipeline runs a Databricks notebook (Python/Scala/Sql/R) in your Azure Databricks workspace.

**Note:** The [Azure Databricks Python Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python) in a Data Factory pipeline runs a Python file in your Azure Databricks cluster.